# Is it possible to re-open a withdrawn article on arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, withdraw

I would like to withdraw an article uploaded on arXiv because the proof contains a fatal mistake and, at the moment, I don't know whether it can be fixed or not. My question is:

> Suppose that I withdraw it on arXiv. Is it possible to re-open it in the future, or should I start a new one?

Ps. I am aware that all uploaded versions (including the withdraw) will be always online. That is why I am waiting before doing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be best to upload a new version that's essentially a note explaining that there's a flaw in the original. Then when you patch the proof (if you patch the proof) you can post the latest version.

Since the flawed original will be there in any case, this keeps all the corrections in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Then, I will wait a couple of days, at most, to search for a patch. Just to avoid many undeletable versions. Does it sound fair?

Comment: I really like this. It seems to be a major advantage over traditional journals where the note on the error and any correction are usually in another issue. It's very hard to be aware that such even exists.

Comment: @puppetsock Luckily, it is not yet published. Of course, the editor will be informed in a couple of days, at most, as well.